# Swift 3: Saving Array to UserDefaults Error - Count of Objects Differs from Count of Keys

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3, nsuserdefaults

My app crashes with error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: count of objects (0) differs from count of keys (1)

Here is how I save my `var favoriteAppAnnotations = [Int: AppAnnotation]()`:

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
let favoritesData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.favoriteAppAnnotations)
userDefaults.set(favoritesData, forKey: "FAVORITES")
userDefaults.synchronize()
```

Here is how I load it:

```
self.favoriteAppAnnotations = [:]
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
if let decoded = userDefaults.object(forKey: "FAVORITES") as? Data {
   let favoritesArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded) as! [Int: AppAnnotation] // THIS IS WHERE THE CRASH IS
   if favoritesArray.isEmpty == false {
       self.favoriteAppAnnotations = favoritesArray
   }
}
```

AppAnnotation conforms to `NSCoding` like this:

```
    class AppAnnotation: ParentAppAnnotation, NSCoding // Note: ParentAppAnnotation is NSObject but doe snot conform to NSCoding
    {
        open var placeId: Int?
        open var placeName: String?
        open var placeDescription: String?
        override init() {
            super.init()
        }
        init(placeId: Int, placeName: String, placeDescription: String) {
            self.placeId = placeId
            self.placeName = placeName
            self.placeDescription = placeDescription
        }
        required convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
            guard let placeName = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "placeName") as? String,
                  let placeDescription = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "placeDescription") as? String
                  else { return nil }
            self.init(placeId: decoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "placeId"),
                    placeName: placeName,
                    placeDescription: placeDescription)

        }
        func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
            coder.encodeCInt(Int32(self.placeId!), forKey: "placeId")
            coder.encode(self.placeName, forKey: "placeName")
            coder.encode(self.placeDescription, forKey: "placeDescription")
        }
    }
```

I am giving up where the problem is. Thinking about alternative ways to save array... such as converting to `JSON` string.
But I'd like to learn where the current problem might be.

Comment: Why are you using `encodeCInt` ? should be `coder.encode(placeId!, forKey: "placeId")`

Comment: BTW why don't you declare your AppAnnotation class properties as constants?

Comment: Thanks, I noted integer encoding. But why properties of class should be constants?

Comment: If you need to change it just create a new object

Comment: BTW UserDefaults has a method called `data(forKey:)`

Comment: I think the problem is with my custom object class. When I passed a very simple custom object class - all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with force unwrap.

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded) as! [Int: AppAnnotation]
```

Use

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded) as? [Int: AppAnnotation]
```

Check out method definition:

```
open class func unarchiveObject(with data: Data) -> Any?
```

It returns optional value.

Comment: Why would that solve the problem? It would only avoid crashing the app.

Comment: Changing to ? did not help. Same error. Could this be the way I construct array: [Int: AppAnnotation]? What if I redo to only [AppAnnotation]?

Comment: Apart from this, everything else looks good. You can uninstall the app and install again. There may be issue with previous persisted data.